# My graph is not showing up and my iPython Notebooks never stops working

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, jupyter-notebook

When I run the code below my iPython Notebooks starts working on it (I see black dot in the top right corner), but it never stops. I cannot stop it either by pressing button with the black square.
I opened my other notebook and it shows the histogram without any problem.
What can be the reason?

Thank you.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import normal
gaussian_numbers = normal(size=1000)
plt.hist(gaussian_numbers)
plt.title("Gaussian Histogram")
plt.xlabel("Value")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.show()
```

**UPDATE:** Created a new notebook. Passed all the code from the previous notebook (including code that gets the data from the internet). Can any other code affect working and displaying the histogram?
There is not other code working when I run histogram.

Comment: It's working for me!

Comment: for me as well, what version of ipython, matplotlib do you have ?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733490/ipython-notebook-stops-evaluating-cells-after-plt-show/28737233

Comment: Cel, thank you. I missed that posted and his suggestions worked. Should I delete this one?

Comment: I suggested a duplicate note which you can accept. Of course you are free to delete your post, but there's no need for that. Often duplicates are not easy to find - so there's no need to be embarrassed either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yo need to use`%matplotlib inline`

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import normal
gaussian_numbers = normal(size=1000)
plt.hist(gaussian_numbers)
plt.title("Gaussian Histogram")
plt.xlabel("Value")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.show()
```

see this other thread to automatically do this on the IPython configuration [Automatically run %matplotlib inline in iPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176731/automatically-run-matplotlib-inline-in-ipython-notebook)