# Repositioning windows in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just started using python. Mostly the output that I have will be 2D-graphs, so I figured matplotlib is the way to go.

When coding I usually position my windows similar to the following screenshot. I assigned hotkeys to these positions using BetterSnapTool on OSX.

[image]

Problem is, that I cannot reposition the python output. Instead of the graph, the python notebook will be repositioned. Is there a possible workaround?

[Of course I could manually move the figure every time, but this always costs some time and focus.]

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `%matplotlib inline` for plotting in your notebook? Opening plots in additional windows is really giving away one of the most powerful features of the notebook.

Comment: See also my answer here: With `%matplotlib notebook` you even get some of the cool interactive features: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28737233/2272172

Comment: Thank you both, I didn't know about that. That solves the question in a different way.